# How do I order elements by children count in firebase?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to order elements by children count of their child. Is there a possible way for this on Java?

Comment: I think the only solution is to keep track of the number of children in data and then use the "OrderByChild". That means you have to handle the count by yourself...

Comment: @Th0rndike good solution, thank you.